# finalize driver install via PnPUtil without restart on windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10, inf, system32

I'm installing some audio drivers using PnPUtil to Windows 10:

```
   pnputil -a ./installaudiodriver.inf /install
```

I run a batch file via powershell, installing 5 INFs. a couple of the INFs include files copy to `%windir%\system32` folder.
**Problem: I don't see those files if I don't restart the system.**

Is there a way to finalized the installation and make Windows refresh\update the system32 folder so those files will be visible?

I want to avoid restarting the system since these actions are done as part of a python script, repeatedly running install and running tests.

- I have tried restarting the `explorer.exe`, but it did not trigger the refresh.
- Installation run with admin privileges.

addition:
If the system goes to standby mode, when woken up (includes entering windows credentials) the files are added to System32.

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "I dont see those files" Using windows explorer > View -> Refresh or CRTL+R or console dir command?

Comment: the files are not displayed. Refreshing or CTRL+R do not show them.

Comment: Than try to verify if files are REALLY copied, catch copy command exitcode

Comment: The copy actions are included in the INF itself. am i missing something?